# Scholarly articles that compare and contrast different thematic map types or discusses what thematic map types are better in certain situations?

Tags: thematic-map

I'm writing a paper that involves some GIS work that I've done and as part of that I need to analyse an existing cluster map and explain why a heat map would be a better solution. I can provide plenty of reasons but they need to be backed up by some sort of literature review. Can anyone suggest a paper that would explain why certain map types would be better than others in different situations? I could use a web article in a pinch but it's better if it's some sort of research paper.